# Where to extract manually downloaded android_m2repository_r36.zip?

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-8.1, android-support-library

I was having problem downloading this zip file(android_m2repository_r36.zip) using android studio as my internet connection is not that awesome. I downloaded the file using Internet Download Manager separately. Please provide steps to solve this problem. I'm on windows operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i figured out how to do this just go to the android folder in filesystem where you're sdk is installed in my case E:\Android\sdk\extras\android\ 
extract the file in his folder and restart android studio. that's it.

Answer (score -1):

The question is to old, but maybe others need to download [last android_m2repository](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-support-repository-download.html) .

After download, `unzip, copy/past` the content on a path similar to

```
 ..\android-sdks\extras\android\m2repository..
```

.Hope its Helps.